# Why the readonly false property is not working for the textbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an MVC dropdown and when its value changes it should make the textbox readonly and editable for certain values. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
$("#Users_UserGroupID").change(function () {
  if ($("#Users_UserGroupID").val != "2") {
    $("#Users_ClientName").prop("readonly", true);
    $("#Users_ClientName").val("")
  } else if ($("#Users_UserGroupID").val == "2") {
    $("#Users_ClientName").attr("readonly", false)
    $("#Users_ClientName").val("")
  }
});
```

Comment: Off-topic, but why do you use both `prop` and `attr` for the same thing in the two branches?

Answer (score 2):

You need to invoke the `val()` method, not compare the reference to `val`. Also note that the logic can be simplified. Try this:

```
$("#Users_UserGroupID").change(function () {
  $("#Users_ClientName").prop("readonly", $("#Users_UserGroupID").val() != "2").val("")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try

```
$("#Users_ClientName").attr("readonly", "readonly");
```

instead of

```
Users_ClientName").prop("readonly", true);
```

as because readonly does not accept true or false.

and to remove you can use

```
$("#Users_ClientName").removeAttr("readonly");
```

Hope this will work.